# DropDownList not issues in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have two DropDownList which are being populated from a database(SQL) on Page_Load. Now I want to take the Text/Value selected from each DropDownList and insert them into a database. But when I click on the button and the OnClick Event is action the DropDownLists go back to the original state and not the selected values get inserted, instead I get the first Text/Value of the DropDownList all the time. How can I prevent this from happening? Any help will really appreciate it.

I'm using C# for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In page load, load up the dropdowns like this

```
protected void Page_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadDropDowns();
    }
}
```

Basically button click causes postback and if you are populating controls in Load event without check for postback, it will repopulate your controls resetting it's state.

Answer (score 0):

Your DDL is getting rebuilt on every page load.  You need to wrap your ddl data source calculation in an

```
if (!IsPostBack)
```

or put it in a part of the lifecycle that only loads once, like the OnLoad()